# Which WDK to install for Windows 10 21H2?

Tags: windows, wdk

I use Windows 10, and `winver` for me says:

[image: winver]

... that it is Windows 10, Version 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1889).

So, I want to install Windows Driver Kit (WDK), but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads?source=recommendations says:

[image: wdk page]

... that is, it lists as closest options:

- Windows 11, version 21H2 (but I have Windows 10?)
- Windows 10, version 2004 (but I have version 21H2?)

So, which WDK should I install? Would I be OK installing the Windows 11, version 21H2 - even if I have Windows 10, version 21H2?

Answer (score 1):

Well, went with Windows 11, version 21H2 - apparently it worked, but who can tell ...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this problem with Visual Studio 2022 and Windows 10 21H2, you need to download WDK [Windows 11, version 22H2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk#download-icon-step-3-install-windows-11-version-22h2-wdk) (weird i know)